# why GridSearchCv behave different in same code

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

i'm trying to call GridSearchCV for best estimators 
and if i call the parameters like this

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

parameters = {'max_depth':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],\
'min_samples_leaf':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],\
'min_samples_split':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}

scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=scorer)

grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_clf = grid_fit.best_estimator_

best_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_train_predictions = best_clf.predict(X_train)
best_test_predictions = best_clf.predict(X_test)

print('The training F1 Score is', f1_score(best_train_predictions, y_train))
print('The testing F1 Score is', f1_score(best_test_predictions, 
y_test))
```

Result would be

```
The training F1 Score is 0.784810126582
The testing F1 Score is 0.72
```

the result would be different from this for the same data 
i only changed the [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] to [2,4,6,8,10]

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

parameters = {'max_depth':[2,4,6,8,10],'min_samples_leaf':[2,4,6,8,10],\
          'min_samples_split':[2,4,6,8,10] }

scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=scorer)
grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_clf = grid_fit.best_estimator_
best_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_train_predictions = best_clf.predict(X_train)
best_test_predictions = best_clf.predict(X_test)

print('The training F1 Score is', f1_score(best_train_predictions, y_train))
print('The testing F1 Score is', f1_score(best_test_predictions, y_test))
```

Result

```
The training F1 Score is 0.814814814815
The testing F1 Score is 0.8
```

Confused how GridsearchCV exactly works

Comment: there are different places randomness can occur.. in your training/test split for example is likely to give rise to different results

Comment: Are you confused about why the scores are different in the two cases or more precisely about why the first is lower than the second?

Comment: Why the score are different

Answer (score 0):

By changing the values analyzed by your gridsearch, you will evaluate and compare your model for different sets of hyperparameters. Remember what GridSearch eventually does is selecting the best set of hyperparameters.

Hence, in your code, `grid_fit.best_estimator_` could be different models, which explains quite naturally why they would yield different scores on the train and test set.

You might have in the first case

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 3, min_samples_leaf = 5, min_samples_split = 9)
```

And in the second case

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 2, min_samples_leaf = 4, min_samples_split = 8)
```

(to check it you can do `grid_fit.best_params_` in each case).

However, you really should have a larger score in the first case, because your second grid search is using a subset of parameters from the first. Like @Attack68 mentioned above, this is likely to be because of randomness for which you do not control at each step.